# Regex Pattern where group may not exist

Tags: regex

I have a RegEx pattern that needs to match on any of the following lines:

```
10-10-15 15:16:41.1 Some Text here 
10-10-15 15:16:41.12 Some Text here 
10-10-15 15:16:41.123 Some Text here 
10-10-15 15:16:41 Some Text here
```

I can match the first 3 with the pattern below:

```
(?<date>(?<day>\d{1,2})-(?<month>\d{1,2})-(?<year>(?:\d{4}|\d{2}))\s(?<time>(?<hour>\d{2}):(?<minutes>\d{2}):(?<seconds>\d{2})\.(?<milli>\d{0,3})))\s(?<Line>.*)
```

How do i Match this line (10-10-15 15:16:41 Some Text here) which has no milliseconds but still get the group back in my result either wit a blank value or with 0 as the value?

Thanks

As i said each of the lines below will match:

```
10-10-15 15:16:41.123 Some text Here
10-10-15 15:16:41.12 Some Text here 
10-10-15 15:16:41.1 Some Text here 
10-10-15 15:16:41. Some Text here
```

The groups look like so:

```
date    [0-18]  `10-10-15 15:16:41.`
day     [0-2]   `10`
month   [3-5]   `10`
year    [6-8]   `15`
time    [9-18]  `15:16:41.`
hour    [9-11]  `15`
minutes [12-14] `16`
seconds [15-17] `41`
milli   [18-18] ``
Line    [19-34] `Some Text here `
```

Comment: Basically what i need to do is make the Milli group Optional to the pattern but to still exist in the resulting group output with either its Value or a Default?

Comment: enclose the dot and the milli in a non-capturing group and make it optional.

Comment: Are you using a specific flavor of RegEx? The provided pattern doesn't match any of the provided text samples and it contains some typically invalid syntax such as question marks at the beginning of capturing groups `(?`…

Comment: @gfullam A valid question, but in OP's defence a lot of regex engines support named groups (which is what `(?<...>...)` is).

Comment: Actually got it. I neede the following pattern: (?<date>(?<day>\d{1,2})-(?<month>\d{1,2})-(?<year>(?:\d{4}|\d{2}))\s(?<time>(?<hour>\d{2}):(?<minutes>\d{2}):(?<seconds>\d{2})(?<milli>\.?\d{0,3})))\s(?<logEntry>.*)

Comment: @Biffen I had no idea. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @KF-SoftwareDev There seems to be some confusion, perhaps you could clear it up. Is the `.` optional, even if milliseconds are present? In other words; is `10-10-15 15:16:41123 Some text Here` valid?

Comment: @Biffen - No the .(dot) is needed if the milliseconds exist. so your example would be invalid because seconds has a max length of 2 specified. However i have just used you example against my new pattern and it matches (this is incorrect) I am working on a fix now   - (?<date>(?<day>\d{1,2})-(?<month>\d{1,2})-(?<year>(?:\d{4}|\d{2}))\s(?<time>(?<hour>\d{2}):(?<minutes>\d{2}):(?<seconds>\d{2})(?<milli>\.?\d{0,3})))\s(?<logEntry>.*)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following (slightly modified version of your regex):

```
(?<date>(?<day>\d{1,2})-(?<month>\d{1,2})-(?<year>(?:\d{4}|\d{2}))\s(?<time>(?<hour>\d{2}):(?<minutes>\d{2}):(?<seconds>\d{2})(?<milli>\.\d{0,3})?))\s(?<logEntry>.*)
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/tC0tS5/5)

Explanation:

- Make the `<milli>` part optional.. and not the `.` since it matches strings like `10-10-15 15:16:41123 Some Text here` also..

Comment: Thanks this works much better then My approach.

One other problem is the Milli group does not exist if the milliseconds are not present - is there a way to give this group a default if the value does not exist?

Comment: yeah.. maybe.,. it will depend on the language you are using :)

Comment: `(?<milli>\.\d{0,3})?` → `(?<milli>(?:\.\d{0,3})?)` ought to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Make the milliseconds optional `?`

```
/^([\d]{2})-([\d]{2})-([\d]{2}|[\d]{4})\s+([\d]{2}):([\d]{2}):([\d]{2})\.?(\d+)?\s+(.*?)$/
```

---

Example:

```
<?php

$strings = <<< LOL
10-10-15 15:16:41.1 Some Text here 
10-10-15 15:16:41.12 Some Text here 
10-10-15 15:16:41.123 Some Text here 
10-10-15 15:16:41 Some Text here 
LOL;

preg_match_all('/^([\d]{2})-([\d]{2})-([\d]{2}|[\d]{4})\s+([\d]{2}):([\d]{2}):([\d]{2})\.?(\d+)?\s+(.*?)$/m', $strings , $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($matches[0]); $i++) {

    $day = $matches[1][$i];
    $month = $matches[2][$i];
    $year = $matches[3][$i];
    $hours = $matches[4][$i];
    $minutes = $matches[5][$i];
    $seconds = $matches[6][$i];
    $ms = $matches[7][$i];
    $text = $matches[8][$i];


    echo "$day $month $year $hours $minutes $seconds $ms $text \n";
}
```

---

Regex Demo:

https://regex101.com/r/aF9wN6/1

---

PHP Demo:

http://ideone.com/1aEt2E

---

Regex Explanation:

```
^([\d]{2})-([\d]{2})-([\d]{2}|[\d]{4})\s+([\d]{2}):([\d]{2}):([\d]{2})\.?(\d+)?\s+(.*?)$

Assert position at the beginning of a line (at beginning of the string or after a line break character) (line feed) «^»
Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «([\d]{2})»
   Match a single character that is a “digit” (any decimal number in any Unicode script) «[\d]{2}»
      Exactly 2 times «{2}»
Match the character “-” literally «-»
Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 2 «([\d]{2})»
   Match a single character that is a “digit” (any decimal number in any Unicode script) «[\d]{2}»
      Exactly 2 times «{2}»
Match the character “-” literally «-»
Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 3 «([\d]{2}|[\d]{4})»
   Match this alternative (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) «[\d]{2}»
      Match a single character that is a “digit” (any decimal number in any Unicode script) «[\d]{2}»
         Exactly 2 times «{2}»
   Or match this alternative (the entire group fails if this one fails to match) «[\d]{4}»
      Match a single character that is a “digit” (any decimal number in any Unicode script) «[\d]{4}»
         Exactly 4 times «{4}»
Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (any Unicode separator, tab, line feed, carriage return, form feed) «\s+»
   Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 4 «([\d]{2})»
   Match a single character that is a “digit” (any decimal number in any Unicode script) «[\d]{2}»
      Exactly 2 times «{2}»
Match the character “:” literally «:»
Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 5 «([\d]{2})»
   Match a single character that is a “digit” (any decimal number in any Unicode script) «[\d]{2}»
      Exactly 2 times «{2}»
Match the character “:” literally «:»
Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 6 «([\d]{2})»
   Match a single character that is a “digit” (any decimal number in any Unicode script) «[\d]{2}»
      Exactly 2 times «{2}»
Match the character “.” literally «\.?»
   Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «?»
Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 7 «(\d+)?»
   Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «?»
   Match a single character that is a “digit” (any decimal number in any Unicode script) «\d+»
      Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (any Unicode separator, tab, line feed, carriage return, form feed) «\s+»
   Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 8 «(.*?)»
   Match any single character that is NOT a line break character (line feed) «.*?»
      Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «*?»
Assert position at the end of a line (at the end of the string or before a line break character) (line feed) «$»
```

Comment: `\.?(\d+)?` should be `(?:\.(\d*))?`. And what's with the `[\d]` instead of `\d`?

Comment: If the milliseconds are optional, then it won't return that group if not matched.

Comment: But if there are milliseconds then is the `.` optional?

Comment: @Biffen sry, the dot `.` is outside the milliseconds group because the OP doesn't need it and it's also optional .

Comment: @Biffen it was due to copy+paste from the first part of the regex. tks for pointing that.

Comment: @PedroLobito Is `12-34-5678 12:34:567890123 Some text Here` valid?

Comment: @Biffen The user isn't trying to validate any date. This `12:34:567890123` isn't valid.

Comment: @PedroLobito I mean the large number of seconds. I'm fairly sure there can be at most two digits for seconds and that if there are any milliseconds the `.` is mandatory. `([\d]{2})\.?(\d+)?` will match `567890123`.

Comment: @PedroLobito By looking at OP's regex and samples.

Comment: @Biffen the best way to show what you know is by answering the question, something you haven't done yet.

Comment: @PedroLobito Hey, I'm not looking for a fight or anything. You have a decent answer here, I just think it's lacking in a minor detail. There are enough nearly identical answers to this question.

Answer (score 0):

```
^(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)\s(\d+):(\d+):(\d+)\.?(\d*)([a-zA-Z\s]+)
```

Note the `(\d*)` which will return the group even if empty.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tV1nS4/3)

Comment: `(\d+|.{0})` could be shortened to `(\d+|)` or even `(\d*)`.

Comment: This will match `10-10-15 15:16:41123 Some text Here`, which I'm not sure OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

Worked it out. I needed the following pattern:

```
(?<date>(?<day>\d{1,2})-(?<month>\d{1,2})-(?<year>(?:\d{4}|\d{2}))\s(?<time>(?<hour>\d{2}):(?<minutes>\d{2}):(?<seconds>\d{2})(?<milli>\.?\d{0,3})))\s(?<logEntry>.*)
```

Comment: Your regex still wont work as expected for values.. it will match `10-10-15 15:16:41345 Some Text here ` [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/tC0tS5/4) also.. whereas it shouldnt.. Check my answer :)

Comment: Cheers just saw that. I have another question just added to the comments for your answer if you could assist? Thanks